# embedding binary rpm inside source tarball

Tags: linux, rpm

I have a pre-built signed rpm that I want to submit to a build system (OBS) which accepts mypkg.spec and mypkg.tar.bz2. I know how to extract the contents of the pre-built rpm (that I can hide in mypkg.tar.bz2) and repackage it into a new rpm from within the spec file. But I want my signature on the rpm to be preserved. So, I am looking for a way to have the build system output my pre-built rpm by using some 'magical' directives in the spec file. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way. Signing of packages are done using obs-sign daemon and there is no way you can workaround it.